# Checkerboard screen tearing on Dell XPS 13 developer edition (Intel iris 640 pro graphics, i915 kernel module)

Tags: 16.04, dell, intel-graphics, xps

I am using a dell developer edition xps 13 (9360), which has intel iris graphics. (i915 module).

When I play full screen video that changes a lot, I see a bunch of screen tearing, which creates a weird checkerboard pattern. It's extremely distracting.

I have found some suggestions to fix this including:

- Edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf to include the line `"Option "TearFree" "true"`(according to the arch wiki).

But this file and directory path don't exist in ubuntu 16.04. I tried editing /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf with the following contents:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

But it doesn't seem to have had any impact. This is directly from the arch wiki. The suggestion mentions an "intel" module but I believe the correct module for my video accelerator is "i915" isn't it? But if I switch "intel" to "i915" I get an xorg crash notice at boot time.

By default there appears to be a file called /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-intel-modesetting.conf which has the following contents:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Configured Video Device"
        Driver "modesetting"
EndSection
```

I've also tried adding the entry there, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

- Install zesty firmwares and kernels in xenial

Sadly this breaks virtualbox dkms which means this isn't a usable solution for me since I use it for development constantly.

I have updated the intel video modules using the updater provided by 01.org.

Does anyone have any possible solutions that I could try to get this working properly? A dist upgrade isn't really an option because it breaks most of the dell integrations that are actually extremeley useful.

Comment: Also seeing this on Arch Linux, but I had suspected it was due to having two monitors running off the card.  How many monitors do you have connected?